# React - What is meant by 'Do not use HOC’s in the render method of a component. Access the HOC outside the component definition.'?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I am learning HOCs and keep reading the above quote, but I do not understand what it means.  If my HOC adds a method to my consuming component, can I use that method in the render method like so?  If not how would I do what I am trying to do here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withMyHOC } from '../with_my_component'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { methodFromHOC }= this.props;
    const result = methodFromHOC(someArgument);

    return (
      <div >
        {result}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withMyHOC(MyComponent );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say, do not use HOC within the render method, it means that you shouldn't create an instance of the component wrapped by HOC within the render method of another component. For example, if you have a App Component which uses MyComponent, it shouldn't be like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { methodFromHOC }= this.props;
    const result = methodFromHOC(someArgument);

    return (
      <div >
        {result}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

---

```
import { withMyHOC } from '../with_my_component'
export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      const Wrap = withMyHOC(MyComponent);
      return (
        <div>
            {/* Other Code */}
            <Wrap />
        </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Why you shouldn't use it like above is because everytime render method is called a new instance of the `MyComponent` is created wrapped by HOC called `Wrap` and hence everytime it be be mounted again instead of going by the natural lifecycle or React.

However if your HOC passes a function as props, you can use it within the render as long as it doens't cause a re-render again otherwise it will lead to a infinite loop.

Also its better to memoize functions which are called in render directly to avoid computation again and again

[**CodeSandbox Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hermann-1vvfv)

Comment: interesting. it was my thought as well but component wrapped into HOC does not seem being remounted to me. could you look into https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-microservice-vqy1u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark ?

Comment: There it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sky-d2c92?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark You're calling `console.log` without wrapping in a callback and calling `withBlur` in the wrong place

Comment: @Dupocas I mean, for my version I'd expect `Input` will be re-created on each host's re-render(like a demo for bad move), but it does not happen.

Comment: @skyboyer that is because, of your updater `const [,updater] = useReducer((x) => x++, 0);` which doesn't update the state unfortunately since you are using a post increment. IF you change it to `const [,updater] = useReducer((x) => ++x, 0); ` you will see the expected behaviour

Comment: oh, crap. you rock!

Answer (score 1):

A `High Order Component` is a `function` which returns a `Component`, not `jsx`. When wrapping a component with an hoc, you're not changing the returned value of your component, you're changing the signature itself. Consider the following `hoc`

```
const withFoo = Component => props =>{
    return <Component {...props} foo='foo' />
}
```

`withFoo` is a `function` which takes a `Component` (not `jsx`) as argument and returns a component. You don't need to call an `hoc` from render because the values it injects are already inside `props` of the wrapped component.

An `hoc` tells how a wrapped component will look like, changes it's definition so the only place to use it is in the component definition itself. Calling an `hoc` inside render creates a new instance of that component on each render. It's the equivalent of

```
const Component = () =>{
    const ChildComponent = () =>{
        return <span> Child </span>
    }

    return <ChildComponent /> //You're declaring again on each render
}
```

Use your high order components like this

```
 const Component = ({ foo }) => <div>{ foo }</div>
 export default withFoo(Component)
```

Or

```
const Component = withFoo(({ foo }) => <div>{ foo }</div>)
```